# I have created Shopify app after installing app I want to take the user to my site with email and shop URL as param

Tags: node.js, express, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const cors = require('@koa/cors');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
const { default: enforceHttps } = require('koa-sslify');
const next = require('next');
const { default: createShopifyAuth } = require('@shopify/koa-shopify-auth');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const { verifyRequest } = require('@shopify/koa-shopify-auth');
const session = require('koa-session');
const { ApiVersion } = require('@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy');
const { default: graphQLProxy } = require('@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy');
dotenv.config();
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 9000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const Router = require('koa-router');
const processPayment = require('./server/router');
const helloMessage = require('./server/router');
const { SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY, SHOPIFY_API_KEY } = process.env;
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cookie = require('cookie');
const nonce = require('nonce')();
const querystring = require('querystring');
const request = require('request-promise');
var bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
const apiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx";
const apiSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const scopes = 'read_products,write_script_tags,read_script_tags,read_customers, write_customers,read_product_listings,read_orders';
const forwardingAddress = "https://qualzz.com:9000"; 
//const forwardingAddress = "https://18.188.232.26:9000"
const appInstallAddress = "https://qualzz.com/api/user/webhooks/userInStalledApp";
const createUserUrlLink = "https://qualzz.com/api/user/createUser";
 const forgotPasswordUrl = "https://qualzz.com/api/user/forgotPassword";
var fs = require('fs');
var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage,
localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
var email = "";
//var key = fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/qualzz.com.key');
//var cert = fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/qualzz_ssl.crt');
//var credentials = {key: key, cert: cert};
//var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, Koa);
// httpsServer.listen(port,()=>{
//     console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
//});

app.prepare().then(() => {
   console.log("Started")
    const server = new Koa();
    const router = new Router();
    server.use(enforceHttps({
     port: port
    }));
    server.use(cors());
    server.use(bodyParser());
    server.use(session(server));
    server.keys = ["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
    router.get('/', processPayment);
    router.get('/hello', async (ctx) => {
      ctx.body = {
        status: 'success',
        message: 'hello, world!'
      };
    })
    module.exports = router;

    router.get('/shopify', (ctx,next) => {
        console.log("ctx -->",ctx.query)
        const shop = ctx.query.shop;
        if (shop) {
            const state = nonce();
            const redirectUri = forwardingAddress + '/shopify/callback';
            const installUrl = 'https://' + shop +
              '/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=' + apiKey +
              '&scope=' + scopes +
              '&state=' + state +
              '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri;
            ctx.cookies.set('state', state);
            console.log("install url ---->",installUrl)
            ctx.redirect(installUrl);
        } else {
            return ctx.status(400).send('Missing shop parameter. Please add ?shop=your-development-shop.myshopify.com to your request');
        }
    });




router.get('/shopify/callback', (ctx,next) => {
  console.log("in ctx call",ctx.query);
    const { shop, hmac, code, state } = ctx.query;
    const stateCookie = cookie.parse(ctx.headers.cookie).state;

    if (state !== stateCookie) {
        return ctx.status(403).send('Request origin cannot be verified');
    }

    if (shop && hmac && code) {
        const map = Object.assign({}, ctx.query);
        delete map['signature'];
        delete map['hmac'];
        const message = querystring.stringify(map);
        const providedHmac = Buffer.from(hmac, 'utf-8');
        const generatedHash = Buffer.from(
        crypto
        .createHmac('sha256', apiSecret)
        .update(message)
        .digest('hex'),
        'utf-8'
        );
        let hashEquals = false;
        try {
          hashEquals = crypto.timingSafeEqual(generatedHash, providedHmac)
        } catch (e) {
          hashEquals = false;
        };

        if (!hashEquals) {
          return res.status(400).send('HMAC validation failed');
        }

        const accessTokenRequestUrl = 'https://' + shop + '/admin/oauth/access_token';
        const accessTokenPayload = {
          client_id: apiKey,
          client_secret: apiSecret,
          code,
        };
//    setTimeOut(()=>{
    console.log("near to redirect"+email);

          ctx.redirect('https://app.qualzz.com?email='+email);  
  //    },500);
     //ctx.redirect('http://www.google.com');
    request.post(accessTokenRequestUrl, { json: accessTokenPayload })
    .then((accessTokenResponse) => {
        const accessToken = accessTokenResponse.access_token;
        const createScriptTagUrl = 'https://'+shop+'/admin/script_tags.json';
        const shopRequestHeaders = {
            'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken,
        };
        const scriptTagBody = {"script_tag":
        {            "event": "onload",
            "src": "https://app.qualzz.com/assets/trackingScript/webtracking.js"
        }
        };
        var redirectUrl = 'https://app.qualzz.com?email='+email;   
        const shopRequestUrl = 'https://' + shop + '/admin/shop.json';
        // const saveCustomerUrl = 'http://ec2-18-216-255-14.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/user/webhooks/userInStalledApp';    
        const saveCustomerUrl = appInstallAddress;
        request.get(shopRequestUrl, { headers: shopRequestHeaders })
        .then((shopResponse) => {
    //script tag try 3

            const shopDetail = {
                "shop":{
                    "id":JSON.parse(shopResponse).shop.id,
                    "email":JSON.parse(shopResponse).shop.email,
                    "phone":JSON.parse(shopResponse).shop.phone,
                    "name":JSON.parse(shopResponse).shop.name,
                    "domain":JSON.parse(shopResponse).shop.domain
                }
            }
            console.log(shopDetail.shop.domain+">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>emailemailxxx<<<<<<<<");
            email = shopDetail.shop.email+'&url='+shopDetail.shop.domain;

            console.log(email);
            const createUser = {
                "email":JSON.parse(shopResponse).shop.email,
                "fullName":JSON.parse(shopResponse).shop.name,
                "password":'XXXXXXXXX',
                "shopify":true
            }
            const createUserUrl = createUserUrlLink;
            request.post({
                 url:saveCustomerUrl,
                 body:shopDetail,
                 json:true
            },function(error,response,body){
                if(!error){
                    console.log("success in saving"+error+response+body);
                    request.post({
                        url: createScriptTagUrl,
                        body: scriptTagBody,
                        headers: shopRequestHeaders,
                        json: true
                    }, function( error,response,body){
                    if (ctx) {
                        console.log("before route -->",redirectUrl) 
                        console.log("ctxroute --->",ctx)
                        ctx.redirect(redirectUrl);
                    } else {
                        ctx.body = {
                            status:error.statusCode,
                            message:'error'
                        }
                    }
                    });
                    ctx.redirect('https://app.qualzz.com?email='+email); 
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                res.status(error.statusCode);
            });
            request.post({
            url:createUserUrl,
            body:createUser,
            json:true
            },function(error,response,body){

                if(!error){
                    console.log("success in user creation");


                }else{ 

                    console.log('Error in user creation',error)
                }
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
    //            redirectSite();
                ctx.body ={
                   status:error.statusCode,
                   message:'error'
                }
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            ctx.body = {
                 status:error.statusCode,
                 message:'error'
            }
        });

            function redirectSite(){     
                server.use((ctx,next) => {
                });    
//script tag try 2

            }

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            ctx.body = {
                status:error.statusCode,
                message:'error'
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400).send('Required parameters missing');
    }
});


    //var dummyObj;
    var shopifyObject;
    router.post('/shopify/plan/upgrade',async(ctx)=>{
        console.log("ctx --->",ctx.request.body);
        obj = ctx.request.body.plan;
        shopifyObject = ctx.request.body.userInfo;
        localStorage.setItem('shopifyObject',JSON.stringify(shopifyObject));
       console.log("shopify object is --->",shopifyObject)
        const upgradeUrl= ctx.request.body.url;
//        ctx.redirect('/');
 //       ctx.redirect(upgradeUrl);
        ctx.body = {
            status:"200",
            message:'success'  
    }
    });
//  console.log("shopiufy object--->",shopifyObject)
      obj = {
      name: 'Recurring charge',
      price: 20.01,
      return_url: "https://qualzz.com:9000",
      test: true
    }
//console.log("calling this ... ");
    server.use(
        createShopifyAuth({
            apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            secret: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            scopes: ['write_products', 'read_products'],
            async afterAuth(ctx) {
                const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.session;
                console.log("Object is -->",obj);
//       localStorage.setItem('shopifyObject', shopifyObject)
                ctx.cookies.set('shopOrigin', shop, { httpOnly: false });
                const stringifiedBillingParams = JSON.stringify({
                    recurring_application_charge: obj
                })
                console.log("in --->",obj)
                const options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: stringifiedBillingParams,
                    credentials: 'include',
                    headers: {
                        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                };
                const confirmationURL = await fetch(
                    `https://${shop}/admin/api/2019-04/recurring_application_charges.json`, options)
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((jsonData) => jsonData.recurring_application_charge.confirmation_url)
                    .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
                    console.log("Confirmation url",confirmationURL)  
                    ctx.redirect('/');

                ctx.redirect(confirmationURL);             
            },
        }),
    );


    server.use(graphQLProxy({version: ApiVersion.April19}))
    server.use(router.routes());
    // server.use(cors());
    server.use(verifyRequest({authRoute: '/shopify/auth', fallbackRoute: '/shopify/auth'}));
    server.use(async (ctx) => {
        await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
        ctx.respond = false;
        ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
        return
    });
    var key = fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/qualzz.com.key');
    var cert = fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/qualzz_ssl.crt');
    var credentials = {key: key, cert: cert};

    https.createServer(credentials, server.callback()).listen(port);

});
```

I have created Shopify app after installing app I want to take the user to my site with email and shop URL as param so as in above code I am redirecting user with email and URL but i am not able to get current user email and store url am getting previous user details so where can i write redirect code so that i will get proper result.
help me for this..

Comment: I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

The correct use is as follows. Shopify merchant installs your App. Once they approve your App, the callback to your App comes with the shop name and a token allowing you access to the Shop details. Use an API call with that token to get the email address you need.

Comment: Shopify has tons of documentation. The code is not difficult. You can manage just fine studying the sample Apps out there. Shopify has a Github with lots of code for you to learn from.

Comment: I did the same as the tutorial but facing issues on redirection all other flow working fine and expected but I need help on redirection and in tutorials, there is no specific clarification on redirection.

Comment: oAuth is fully covered by perhaps hundreds of tutorials! It is a pattern used by most, if not all big systems these days. Shopify is doing nothing special with oAuth. They use it like every other system out there. If you search for oAuth tutorials, you will surely find one you like.